# rails wrong year -4712

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
irb(main):002:0> require 'date'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> x = Date.new
=> #<Date: -4712-01-01 ((0j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

As you can see year is set to -4712.
What do I do wrong?
Year on my ubuntu is set right:

> Oct  4 01:39:58 STD 2017

Answer (score 4):

For the current date, use `today`:

```
2.4.2 :002 > require "date"
 => true 
2.4.2 :003 > x = Date.today
 => #<Date: 2017-10-03 ((2458030j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answer in [official documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-new):

```
# Date.new([year=-4712[, month=1[, mday=1[, start=Date::ITALY]]]])    ->  date
# 
# Creates a date object denoting the given calendar date.
# 
# In this class, BCE years are counted astronomically.  Thus, the
# year before the year 1 is the year zero, and the year preceding the
# year zero is the year -1.  The month and the day of month should be
# a negative or a positive number (as a relative month/day from the
# end of year/month when negative).  They should not be zero.
# 
# The last argument should be a Julian day number which denotes the
# day of calendar reform.  Date::ITALY (2299161=1582-10-15),
# Date::ENGLAND (2361222=1752-09-14), Date::GREGORIAN (the proleptic
# Gregorian calendar) and Date::JULIAN (the proleptic Julian
# calendar) can be specified as a day of calendar reform.
# 
#    Date.new(2001)            #=> #<Date: 2001-01-01 ...>
#    Date.new(2001,2,3)        #=> #<Date: 2001-02-03 ...>
#    Date.new(2001,2,-1)       #=> #<Date: 2001-02-28 ...>
```